# Why can't my other Ubuntu machines have read/write access to my samba shares, when Windows machines do?

Tags: samba

I have a samba share set up on my server, and most of my other machines are running Ubuntu.  On my Ubuntu machines, I end up with read-only access to my files, but Windows machines can read and write.

Here is my smb.conf file:

```
[Fileserver]
 comment = Theta Shared Folder
 path = /mnt/md0/theta
 browsable = yes
 guest ok = yes
 force user = nobody
 read only = no
 create mask = 0755
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So what's your question? Nevermind. I see your question is in the title. My bad. How do you mount the share on Ubuntu?

Comment: Include the full samba configuration, along with the groups/users you want to give access.